# How to process the ASCII in Python3.65?

Tags: string, python-3.x, python-2.7, io

there is a log file to process, which comes from a machine of the other company.
They are using Python2.7, so the file is encoded by ASCII. But in my team, we are using Python3.65. 
When I

```
fileopen = open(my_file, 'rb')
file_content = fileopen.read()
```

I find the file_content is automatically decoded by UTF-8.How to handle this?[image]

Comment: I hope to keep the file_content in python2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of the way your editor is displaying the data.  If you read a file in binary you will get the same bytes you wrote.  They are are just bytes, not encoded as anything.  Your *editor* looks like it is decoding the string for display...incorrectly.

Below I write a file in binary with Python 3.6 and read it back with 2.7 and 3.6:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('test.txt','wb').write(b'\x8c\x8d\x91\x8c')
4

Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('test.txt','rb').read()
'\x8c\x8d\x91\x8c'

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('test.txt','rb').read()
b'\x8c\x8d\x91\x8c'
```

In both cases the same four bytes read are the ones written.

Try displaying the value of the bytes instead of the strings:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b = open('test.txt','rb').read()
>>> for c in b:
...  print(hex(c))
...
0x8c
0x8d
0x91
0x8c

Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b = open('test.txt','rb').read()
>>> for c in b:
...  print hex(ord(c))
...
0x8c
0x8d
0x91
0x8c
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You make me understand some basic knowledge. And how to get a string but not a bytes-like object after 'read()' in python3.65?

Comment: @edcSam `.decode()` to a text string, `.encode()` to bytes.  The default encoding is `utf8` in Python 3 and `ascii` in Python 2, but you can specify a different one.  The elements in a `str` are Unicode codepoints in Python 3.  Python 2 `str` is equivalent to `bytes` in Python 3.  Python 2 `unicode` is equivalent to `str` in Python 3.  Also, if you know the encoding of the file you read, use `open(filename,encoding='utf8')` and you won't need to decode after read.